# maplibre-gl - clusteered source doesn't render some of the features

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl, maplibre-gl

I have a clustered geojson source with more than 500 features. I added two layers for this source: one for rendering single features when there is no `point_count` and another when there is `point_count` (based on this example in the docs: https://maplibre.org/maplibre-gl-js-docs/example/cluster/).

The issue is some of the features (mainly towards the end of the features array) do not render at all, either as clusters or single circles, no matter how far I zoom in.

Here's an example that shows the issue: https://codepen.io/kaveh/pen/NWaaOaQ.

The red circles are from a separate non-clustered source and layer called `stations` and `stations-single` respectively, which are there to show that all features can actually be rendered. The layer has a click event that shows the coordinates in a popup.

The clustered source (called `clustered-stations`) and its layers are after line 6121 and are rendered in shades of blue/green.

If you click on "Zoom to missing station" at the bottom of the map, it zooms the map to station 353, rendered by `stations-single` in red, but not by `clustered-stations`. As you can see, some other stations in the `clustered-stations` layer are rendered fine.

Am I doing something wrong with the styling of my clustered layers or their filters? Or is this a bug in `maplibre-gl` (and possibly `mapbox-gl`, though I haven't tested it with mapbox)?

Answer (score 1):

I found the source of the problem. It's caused by `supercluster`, one of the dependencies of `maplibre-gl`. It expects the longitudes to be within the [-180, 180] range and anything beyond that range gets dropped.

The quick workaround is to fix the coordinates. I've also submitted a PR to do this in `supercluster`: https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster/pull/194.